# How is Rinkeby different from mainnet?

Tags: testnets, rinkeby

What makes Rinkeby a "testnet"? I understand it's a parallel network so my ether there has no effect on the mainnet ether. But how is it different technically?

But does it still run on miners? What incentive would miners have to maintain the testnet?

Could people simply decide that Rinkeby ether is not that bad and start trading it as a currency in itself??

Does it reset itself periodically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of comparison of different test networks here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27048/comparison-of-the-different-testnets

Comment: Are you asking them really, what, in their written source code, enables them to be a/the higher authority... They code better than you do?

Comment: No that’s not what I was asking at all. @user55764

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What makes Rinkeby a "testnet"? I understand it's a parallel network so my ether there has no effect on the mainnet ether. But how is it different technically?

Rinkeby is a Proof-of-Authority network, so uses a different consensus mechanism to the main net. The Ropsten testnet is Proof-of-Work, so more similar to the public main net.

> But does it still run on miners?

Rinkeby doesn't, Ropsten does.

> What incentive would miners have to maintain the testnet?

This doesn't apply to Rinkeby, but if we consider Ropsten: there's no real *financial* incentive, unless there's an elicit black market for testnet ether I've not heard about. (I wouldn't be surprised if there was.) Mining helps the developer community, so the incentive is the same as any other altruistic act.

> Could people simply decide that Rinkeby ether is not that bad and start trading it as a currency in itself??

Yes, they *could*, but...

> Does it reset itself periodically?

...yes. Rinkeby, being PoA, is run by centralised nodes which can be taken down whenever. (I'm uncertain who actually runs them. Anyone?)

Ropsten, being an open PoW network, is more decentralised. However, given the lower rate of hashing being used to mine the blocks, and therefore secure the network, it wouldn't take much to attack and/or ruin. (The original testnet, Morden, had to be taken down, as did the first iteration of Ropsten. We're currently on the Ropsten "Revival" network.)

Answer (score 0):

> Could people simply decide that Rinkeby ether is not that bad and start trading it as a currency in itself??

Lack of scarcity is why test network ether is "that bad" - you do not need to invest anything to acquire, but you do stake your reputation - see https://faucet.rinkeby.io/

Answer (score -1):

Rinkeby is for testing your contracts and the ethers are not real on it ..it's just for testing ..mainnet is live eherum block chain with real ether transactions

Comment: “Ether is not real on it”. My point was, ether is only as real as people willing to buy it. My question was, what makes ether on testnets less real than on the mainnet

Comment: All the faucets handing out Ether to all and sundry.