# How could I measure the total delay (time) to confirm the transaction?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, rinkeby, timestamp

First of all, I'm new to the Erthereum world, I need some help in measuring the total delay (time) require for confirming the transaction.
I have **a decentralized application over a Rinkeby network**, and I want to know, how long the process will take until confirming the transaction?

I have been read in many papers that a total delay is 10 seconds, 15 seconds, 5.5 sec...etc
My question:

How they measure these numbers "10 sec,15 sec..etc"? 
Is it manually, or there is a specific tool or way for measuring the total delay (time).

Comment: The answer is that an elapse of 12 blocks guarantees that your transaction remains in the blockchain with a probability of 99.99%. So this factor is what typically being measured. How many seconds does it take? On mainnet, it is currently 15-17 per blocks, but it will not necessarily remain the same for eternity. On rinkeby... well, who cares? Just measure 12 blocks instead of however many seconds.

Comment: So appreciate your reply, but actually I couldn't understand the provided information. I'm looking to determine the amount of time need to confirm the transaction. For example, I have to wait 10 seconds to approve my transaction and add it to the block. **How can I measure the 10 Seconds?**

Comment: **Don't measure seconds, measure blocks.**

Comment: Could you expalin what do you mean in "An elapse of 12 blocks guarantees that your transaction remains in the blockchain." Thanks a lot

Comment: You execute a transaction at block N. If the transaction-hash is still valid at block N+12, then the probability that the transaction will remain in the blockchain forever is higher than 99.99%. So you don't need to measure how many seconds have elapsed since you executed the transaction, you need to measure how many **blocks** have elapsed since you executed the transaction.

Comment: in above code, the blocklatency is the number of blocks( it is not in seconds).
and elapsed time is calculated based on the time when transaction was collated in the block how do you combine these two to calculate the overall transaction latency ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the exact same thing and the way i measure time it takes and "block-latency" for transaction to finish is by taking the following steps. I'm using web3.js

1. Get current block. `currBlock = web3.eth.getBlockNumber()`
2. Start a timer. `startTime = Date.now()`
3. Fire off a transaction
4. When resolving the promise (the transaction) in the `.then(receipt)` elapsed time can be caluclated with `Date.now() - startTime` and calculate the block latency by doing `receipt.blocknumber - currBlock`

Below is an example of how you could do this assuming you have an array of promises/transactions

```js
async function calculateLatencies(promisesArr) {
  const currBlock = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
  let startTime = Date.now()
  await Promise.all(promisesArr)
    .then(async (receipts) => {
      let elapsedTime = Date.now - startTime
      let lastBlock = receipts[0].blockNumber
      receipts.forEach((receipt) => {
        lastBlock =
          receipt.blockNumber > lastBlock ? receipt.blockNumber : lastBlock
      })
      let blockLatency = lastBlock - currBlock
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your code and helpful info. Did you try it on the Rinkeby network? Because I noticed from EtherScan, the block latency is 15 seconds between all blocks regardless of the gas price?

Comment: @Byo0ona No problem!:) If I answered your question please feel free to accept the answer. My contract is on the Ropsten network. Rinkeby is different to Ropsten in that it employs PoA rather than PoW so it is not a good network to gauge "performance" of how your contract would behave on the mainnet. A link to a post about the differences between rinkeby and mainnet [Rinkeby vs mainnet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/37465/how-is-rinkeby-different-from-mainnet)